# Gremlin-Python Bindings

Tags: python-3.x, tinkerpop3

I started to study about [bindings](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_bindings) and it seemed that it will improve the speed of commonly executed query and I went ahead to try it out.

My query was pretty simple:

```
g.V(('id', 1))
```

but its not working

```
File "/home/galaxia/PycharmProjects/helloworld/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 106, in data_received
    "{0}: {1}".format(status_code, data["status"]["message"]))
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: startup failed:
Script19.groovy: 1: expecting ')', found ',' @ line 1, column 10.
   g.V(('id', 1))
            ^
```

I feel i followed the syntax mentioned in the [doc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_bindings). Did I miss something?

[image]

---

- python3
- tinkerpop 3.3.1
- neo4j 3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to clarify a some things first. Are you sending `g.V(('id', 1))` as a script to Gremlin Server like:

```
client = Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g', pool_size=1)
client.submit("g.V(('id', 1))").all().result()
```

or are you using a remote traversal like:

```
>>> graph = Graph()
>>> g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
>>> g.V(('id', 1))
```

If you are sending scripts, then you aren't using bindings properly. That documentation you linked to is for the latter approach and if you tried the former with that syntax I would imagine you getting that particular error. If you want to use bindings with the scripts then you would want to do this:

```
client = Client('ws://localhost:459408182/gremlin', 'g', pool_size=1)
client.submit("g.V(id)", {'id':1}).all().result()
```

For that kind of usage you will see a noticeable improvement in performance.

Now, if you were doing the latter and using remote traversals, then the first thing to understand is that the documentation isn't completely clear on what the performance improvement is. At this time, the performance enhancement only comes with bindings if your traversal includes a lambda. That was supposed to be a temporary limitation, but it was never implemented further (though it is something being examined now as for this writing). So, since your traversal (in this example) has no lambda you won't see a performance boost for using bindings.

That said, your traversal above should still work in this context and you should not be getting an error. I'm going to assume that you were submitting scripts though when you got this error as I can't think of how else you could have ended up with this output otherwise. If that is not the case, I can try to expand further.

Comment: **client.submit("g.V(id)", {'id':1}).all().result()**
 is throwing *gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 499: The [eval] message supplies one or more invalid parameters key of [[id]] - these are reserved names.*

Comment: **client.submit("g.V(title)", {'title': 'ABCD'}).all().result()**
 throws *python3.5/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py", line 106, in data_received
    "{0}: {1}".format(status_code, data["status"]["message"]))
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: For input string: "TRF_68326*

Comment: **data = client.submit("g.V(1).values('title')").all().result()** this works so I know the data is there in the db

Comment: sorry - `id` is reserved in Gremlin Server as it means `T.id` over there so your first error makes sense. I would have expected the second to work (though it may return no results as I sense you don't have a vertex with the `id` of `ABCD`. That said, I don't understand the error message of that one. can you do something more simple like: `client.submit('x + x', {'x': 2}).all().result()` and see if you get "4"?

Comment: **gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: Unknown vertex id type: id** throws *gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 597: Unknown vertex id type: id*

also tried combinations of having T and not having it.

Comment: Well - scripts/bindings are working so you just have a problem with your gremlin at this point from what i can tell. I think you want to do something like: `client.submit("g.V().has('title',title)", {'title': 'ABCD'}).all().result()` where "ABCD" is the actual title of a vertex in your graph. If that doesn't work, i'd look at the server logs to try to gather more details on what the actual error is.

Comment: AWS Neptune does not support binding. Any work-around for that? other-than totally removing bindings out from existing code which works fine with NEO4J. Basically trying to get same code to work for both NEO4J and Neptune

Comment: hmm - not sure what you can do to fix that. i suppose that if you were just trying Neptune to compare to Neo4j you could try to setup a proxy to Neptune via Gremlin Server. In other words, in Gremlin Server make `g` be your connection to Neptune https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-java.html and then you can point your python client at Gremlin Server. :/   might work. maybe not a great solution for production situations.

Comment: This might be another reason to not use scripts and stick to bytecode based traversals. Of course, CosmosDB doesn't yet support bytecode (though that support is coming). Anyway, both of these products are fairly new so I guess it is expected that we'll see some gaps - I would think that these interoperability problems will smooth out over time.

Comment: bytecode based traversal means `g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.....` ????

Comment: yes...that will convert the traversal to bytecode to submit to the server